# Getting the average for each elements

Tags: r

I have a "Store" data which includes the product1/2's price, sales and the store name. And I want to calculate the average of product sales for each store.

**Selcting store number 1**

```
Store1=Store[(Store$StoreNum==1),]
```

**Computing the means from store 1**

```
STORE1  =colMeans(Store1[c("p1price","p2price")])
```

By doing this, I can get the individual answer but is there any way to compute the mean of each store at once?

I want to solve this with the very very base level of R, not complicating one.

Answer (score 1):

We can do a `group_by` mean with `dplyr`.  Use 'StoreNum' in the group by statement, and with `summarise_at`, loop through the columns of interest to get the `mean`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(StoreNum) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(matches("price")), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Or using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(StoreNum ~ ., df1[c("StoreNum", "p1price","p2price")], mean)
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without 'aggregate'?

Comment: @Sophie  Sorry, it is not clear from the comment.  How do you want the result to be?

Comment: I figured it out!! Thanks :)